# Fixing R class package

Tags: android

Is it possible to tweak the build process and fix the R class package?

For example, can I have "org.test" as my package in the manifest and the build tools to generate the R class in "com.another.package"?

Comment: If you are using Android Studio and Gradle for Android, you can have `applicationId` in `build.gradle` as a distinct value from the `package` attribute in the manifest. The `package` attribute will be where `R` is generated. From the standpoint of determining if two apps have the same "package name", though, the `applicationId` is used. I am not aware of any way of doing what you are requesting, though. What is your use case?

Comment: I have a single project and I generate a bunch of apps from it using a script, just replacing resources (images, logos, strings...) and other things, the package name among them. But when my script replaces the package in the manifest, I have to change the R class package in every single class using it.

Comment: That sounds like you should be using Android Studio/Gradle for Android and product flavors. You keep your `R` in a consistent package, but you get distinct `applicationId` values for distribution purposes.

Comment: I see. Will give it a try, but seems to be what I was looking for. More info here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So CommonsWare is right, you can find more info here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

> - The final package that is used in your built .apk's manifest, and is the package your app is known as on your device and in the Google Play store, is the "application id".
> - The package that is used in your source code to refer to your R class, and to resolve any relative activity/service registrations, continues to be called the "package".